# Call NSNotification selector directly

Tags: objective-c, notifications, observers

I add an observer

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(handleScreenBrightnessMonitoringNotification:)
               name:UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];
```

In one of my methods, I hope to call `handleScreenBrightnessMonitoringNotification` directly without using postNotification. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: It depends on whether the method does anything with the notification that it receives.  Have you tried it to see whether it works in your case?

Comment: @PhillipMills My method does nothing with the notification. I think my problem is that I am not sure how to call my selector.

Comment: @PhillipMills I think I get it. Is it ``[self performSelector:@selector(handleScreenBrightnessMonitoringNotification:)
               withObject:@"UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification"];``?

Comment: Or maybe just `[self handleScreenBrightnessMonitoringNotification:nil]` if the notification parameter is not used.

Comment: Although, in real code, I'd probably create a `handleScreenBrightness` method with no parameters and call it from both the notification handler and your new code just so the unused notification didn't confuse me some day.

Comment: @PhillipMills I delete parameter for my handle method and when I use [self handleScreenBrightnessMonitoringNotification:nil] it says no visible `@interface for my class declares this handle method. Is there something I miss here?

Comment: I think this works ``[self handleScreenBrightnessMonitoringNotification];``

Comment: Good.  The code you posted specified `handleScreenBrightnessMonitoringNotification:` with the colon, which means one parameter.  That's why I assumed you'd need to pass `nil`.